# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), found shape=(32, 32, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a student studying deep learning using the cifar10 dataset these days.

I tried to create a classification by making a simple model with Keras, but the following error kept popping up.
=> "ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), found shape=(32, 32, 3)"

If possible, is there anyone who could help me that what I'm making a mistake?

I also attached the code link of my colab.

: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nt-esA4cgbLX3Eqb7lLIrQ5ok7Fv_ST1?usp=sharing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI0lu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your test set prints this: `<TensorSliceDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(10,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>` It's defined incorrectly.

Instead of `.from_tensor_slices()`, try `.from_tensors()`. (I'm not sure exactly why the tensors are being generated like that) When I ran your code with that change, it worked. The main difference between the two are: the former generates tensors per row inside a dataset, while the latter generates a large tensor containing everything.

```
# Convert the data into TensorFlow Dataset objects
train_normal = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
test_data_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((x_test, y_test))
train_normal = (train_normal.map(data_normalize_and_resize, num_parallel_calls = AUTO).batch(batchSize).prefetch(AUTO))
```

Then your test data prints:

```
test_data_set
# <TensorDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(10000, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(10000, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

[image: Training model]

Comment: [According to this post](https://gist.github.com/robertlugg/52e42c4506c8abf6e3a51c62a68e6c5f), when using `from_tensor_slices()`, the inputs should be the same length, so possibly one axis is being dropped?

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Now I think I need to look more about from_tensor_slices() function.

Comment: That's really weird actually, because I mainly use `.from_tensor_slices()` if making my datasets from arrays and I've never run into this problem. I would've expected your code to work as is, but I guess there's something else going on with that function. I don't remember the issue being there when creating the training set. It removed the 0th axis from both inputs.